# Fix 401 Unauthorized Exception uploading file to SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, csom, file-upload, wcf

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS on Domain 1. This service is accepting a request to upload a file, and then uploading the file to a SharePoint 2010 Server on Domain 2, using the client object model.

Everything works fine when I hardcode the username, password & domain using:

```
context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, password, domain);
```

However, due to the compliance & security we cannot do this in our company. We need to use integrated security if possible. I have tried setting the credentials to both

```
context.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
context.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

But neither appear to work, we receive the error

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>           at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>           at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()
>           at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()
>           at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()
>           at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

Can someone provide any tips on how to fix this? Or tips that might lead us to the resolution, logs to check etc. I am not the developer of the SharePoint site, but can chase them down. I have gone through many questions/answers here and none seem to help us.

Comment: What credentials do you need? Current user's or apppool's?

Comment: app pool credentials

Answer (score 0):

Set the authentication mode as shown below

```
context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
```

Also make sure the application pool account under which the service is hosted in IIS has proper access to SharePoint document library.

Comment: Yes I should have stated this account already has Full Control on the document library in question

Comment: Just to confirm this account has access, I passed the app pools identity credentials directly in and it worked,

Comment: I have modified the answer with correct way to set the authentication mode for client context.

Comment: I have tried this already and does not work

Answer (score 0):

It won't work with default credentials because application pool identity is not there in normal context. If you check the result of [`System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, you'll see it returns `IUSR` instead.

If you want to execute code with app pool credentials, you need to elevate permissions using [`SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges%28v=office.15%29.aspx).